# How to take input of different datatypes in single line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from itertools import permutations



s, n = ???


permList = list (permutations(s),n)

for item in permList:
    print(item)
```

In the code above I want to take input the value of S as string and n as integer. How can I do that ?

Comment: `s, n = "string", 123`

Comment: By "input variable" you mean you want to get the input interactively from the user, using `input`?

Comment: If you can't do something in one line, the next logical step would be to do it in two lines. Which will as a side-effect increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

use a tuple (s,n)=("0",0)

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
x, y = int(input()), float(input())
print(x, y)
```

**Input and output**

```
11
22
11 22.0
```